# Object Oriented PHP issues using a class, involving PrestaShop module

Tags: php, oop, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

**What I want to accomplish**

I am altering a PrestaShop module that currently uses a form submitted by a user to generate files to be a stand alone CRON job. The module works perfectly in the back office, and involves nothing more than a user clicking a button; a repetitive task that should instead be handled by a CRON job (the action, not the clicking of the button of course).

**What I am trying**

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    // Initialize prestashop
    require_once '../../config/config.inc.php';
    require_once '../../init.php';

    define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
    echo 'This gets echoed';
    $exporter = new order_exporter;
    echo 'This does not get echoed';
}

class order_exporter extends Module
{
    // Rest of code here. Works when used with back office.
}
```

**The behavior I am getting**

The first echo works, but once I call `$exporter = new order_exporter;`, I get this error. `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'order_exporter' not found in C:\wamp\www\addressstamps\modules\order_exporter\order_exporter.php`. This isn't on the screen and only in my error log. As I've understood in the past, this is the correct way to use OOP. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding something about Prestashop, OOP, or Scope, but after much research and tweaking, I have made no progress past this point.

Comment: Where is the source file located?

Comment: It is the only file in the module, other than config.xml logo.gif, ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an OOP issue, but a PrestaShop design decision.

Try with:

```
$exporter = Module::getInstanceByName('order_exporter');
```

instead of:

```
$exporter = new order_exporter;
```

Here 'order_exporter' is your module name (i.e the name property from the class).